# Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I just downgraded Angular(to 1.5.7) and typescript(to 2.3.0) and this error showed up

> Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015'.

this is my tsconfig.json File where error is occurred

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, you downgraded from Angular2+ to AngularJS? Why did you do that, or even better, how?

Comment: i'm starting to learn it so i was told to do it with these versions

Comment: Angular and AngularJS are two different frameworks. Considering how your `tsconfig.json` looks like, I guess you want to learn `Angular`. Yay! Anyways, I can advise you to look at the [official guides](https://angular.io/docs), they are very useful and never downgrade to anything lower than v2. Or even better, never downgrade at all, newer is always better